# How to use a spring profile bean in another bean with default profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I have a bean under the "dev" profile:

```
@Bean(name="internalDL")
public Map<Client, List<String>> internalDistributionLists() {
    Map<Client, List<String>> distributionLists = new HashMap<Client, List<String>>();
    distributionLists.put(Client.DL_NAME, Arrays.asList("example@blah.com"));
    return distributionLists;
}
```

I need to use this bean in another bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("internalDL")
private Map<String, List<String>> internalMailingList;

@Bean(name="internalMailingDetails")
public Map<Client, MailingDetails> internalMailingDetails() {
    Map<Client, MailingDetails> internalMailingDetails = new HashMap<Client, MailingDetails>();

    MailingDetails details = new MailingDetails();

    details.setMailingList(internalMailingList.get(Client.DL_NAME));
    details.setTemplateSubject("someTemplate");
    details.setTemplateBody("someTemplate");
    internalMailingDetails.put(Client.DL_NAME, details);

    return internalMailingDetails;
}
```

Now the mailing template is the same for all environments so i haven't put it in a config that's marked with a particular profile.

I tried initializing the profile both by initializing the `ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>` class:

```
@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
}
```

and by putting it as a context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

None of them seem to work though. It keeps throwing a bean not found exception.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework.invocator.wiring.configuration.pojo.common.RootConfig.internalMailingList

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Autowired doesn't work for collection beans. Use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowire`

```
@Resource
private Map<String, List<String>> internalMailingList;
```

And refer [beans-property-is-not-setting-from-utillist-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167789/beans-property-is-not-setting-from-utillist-object/33170175#33170175)

If you are using Spring 4.x later have a look at [spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics)