# Spring dependency injection in external jar

Tags: spring, spring-integration, autowired, spring-bean, spring-ioc

I have a project A which is consuming a jar lets say `B.jar` (where B is another project used as a dependency in our project A), now there is a `Bean` (kind of a `Spring-gemfire` cache), which holds all the required data in a map. 
This map bean is being used by project (included as `jar` in my project) i.e B to read the cache properties , but i am unable to do so any help ?

my webapp-config.xml for project B

```
    <!-- Injecting bean in our A application -->
    <bean id="foo" class="com.abc.solutions.Foo" init-method="loadFoo">
             <property name="bar1" ref="gemFireBean"/>
             <property name="bar2" ref="commonBean"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="b2" class="java.util.HashMap"
       factory-bean="foo" factory-method="createB2" autowire="byName">
    </bean>
```

the above bean b2  has to be used in external project B (included as jar in my project A).

part of clas sin project B2

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("b2")
    private Map<String, String> mapFromA;
```

but i am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: a `HashMap` (or any other generic container like arrays or collections) should never be a Spring Bean.
Only business objects should be beans, not infrastructure containers.

You can circumvent this by building a custom object around your map and injecting this. In your case, you should inject your `foo` bean, and get the map from it programmatically.

---

What happens in your case is outlines in [the `@Autowired` section of the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is
>   String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type,
>   and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

    private Map<String, MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs;

    @Autowired
    public void setMovieCatalogs(Map<String, MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs) {
        this.movieCatalogs = movieCatalogs;
    }

    // ...

}
```

I.e. Spring thinks you want a map where the keys are the bean names and the values are beans of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through `@Autowired`, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use `@Resource` for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.

refer : [beans-property-is-not-setting-from-utillist-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167789/beans-property-is-not-setting-from-utillist-object/33170175#33170175)

and Spring [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)